# Include Other option in Ajax cascading drop down using JSP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, cascadingdropdown

I have created a cascading drop down menu for my registration page where I am fetching the counries from the database and base don the countries the states would be retrieved.

Everything is working good but I am not understanding how to include the OTHER option in the drop down select option in the last of the drop down select.

The following is the code I have written for displaying countries in Countries_States.jsp :

```
<tr>
                <td>Country : </td>
                <td>
                    <%

                        try {
                            MylistDAO dao = new MylistDAO();
                            ResultSet rs = dao.getCountries();
                            String ss;
                    %> <select id="combos" name="combos"
                    onChange="showcity(this.value);" onfocus="return(validCountry(this));">
                        <%
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                    ss = rs.getString(2);
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=ss%>"><%=ss%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </select> <%
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 %>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

The following is the code for retrieving list of states based on countries in AJAX :-

```
function showcity(str) {

    document.getElementById("states").length = 0;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getCity.jsp?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            var tags = xml.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for ( var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                var combo = document.getElementById("states");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = tags[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                option.value = tags[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                try {
                    combo.add(option, null); //Standard 
                } catch (error) {
                    combo.add(option); // IE only 
                }

            }

    };
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

ALso the following is the getCity.jsp page to retrieve the list of states based on country :

```
 <% 
    String names = request.getParameter("q");
    out.print(names);
    try {
        MylistDAO dao =new MylistDAO();
        //GetCity c = new GetCity();
        ResultSet rs = dao.getState(names);
        String xml = "<table>";
        while (rs.next()) {
            xml += "<tr>";
            xml += "<td>";
            xml += rs.getString(1);
            xml += "</td>";
            xml += "</tr>";
        }
        xml += "</table>";
        out.print(xml);
        //con.close();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        pw.write(xml);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
%>
```

The following is my DAO.java class to fetch the data from database to populate the drop downs :

```
 public class MylistDAO {
    public Connection con;
    public Statement st;

    public Statement  get_connection()
    {
        try{
            con=DaoConnections.connection();
            st=con.createStatement();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }finally{
            try{if(con==null){
                con.close();
            }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return st;
    }
    public ResultSet getCountries()
    {   
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement st=null;
        try{
            MylistDAO dao= new MylistDAO();
            st=dao.get_connection();
            rs= st.executeQuery("select * from countries");

        }catch (Exception e){}
        return (rs);
    }

    public ResultSet getState(String countryname)
    {   
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement st=null;
        try{
            MylistDAO dao= new MylistDAO();
            st=dao.get_connection();
            rs= st.executeQuery("select s.stateName as statename from states s,countries c where s.countryID=c.countryId and c.countryName= '"+ countryname+"'" );

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return (rs);
    }
}
```

I want to just add an option of OTHER in both the countries and states dropdown based on which an OTHER text box should display and I could enter the other state value in that. I tried the following in getCity.jsp :

```
  <% 
    String names = request.getParameter("q");
    out.print(names);
    try {
        MylistDAO dao =new MylistDAO();
        //GetCity c = new GetCity();
        ResultSet rs = dao.getState(names);
        String xml = "<table>";
        while (rs.next()) {
            xml += "<tr>";
            xml += "<td>";
            xml += rs.getString(1);
            xml += "</td>";
            xml += "</tr>";
        }
xml += "<tr>";
            xml += "<td>";
            xml += "Other";
            xml += "</td>";
            xml += "</tr>";
        xml += "</table>";
        out.print(xml);
        //con.close();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        pw.write(xml);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
%>
```

but it did not work. Please help me in adding the OTHER option in the select and I am a fresher so please help me giving sample code and only provide me cod ein JavaScript JSP or Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any extra plugins,

```
var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'text1',
    val2 : 'text2'
};
var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

If you had lots of options, or this code needed to be run very frequently, then you should look into using a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) instead of modifying the DOM many times unnecessarily. For only a handful of options, I'd say it's not worth it though.

`DocumentFragment` is good option for speed enhancement, but we cannot create option element using `document.createElement('option')` since IE6 and IE7 are not supporting it.

What we can do is, create a new select element and then append all options. Once loop is finished, append it to actual DOM object.

```
var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'text1',
    val2 : 'text2'
};
var _select = $('<select>');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    _select.append(
            $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
        );
});
$('#mySelect').append(_select.html());
```

This way we'll modify DOM for only one time!

you might be interested in this [cheat sheet](http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf) (PDF) on using jQuery with selects for more info.

**Using Javascript**

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function function1() {
        var newOption = document.createElement('<option value="TOYOTA">');
        document.all.mySelect.options.add(newOption);
        newOption.innerText = "Toyota";
    }
    function function2() {
        document.all.mySelect.options.remove(0);
    }
</script>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="function1();">
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="function2();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response but I dnt wanna use jquery in my application and because dis is jst a small level project dere r no constraint of application performance and all.

Comment: yeah but u mentioned only for static dro down.. what if I am populatibg the second drop down from database.